# Unity 2d collision with the edge of the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, collision

*I'm not sure if the title is correct*. **I'm new to unity** and I'm trying to make a simple **(2D) pong**. The problem is that I'm trying to do something different from tutorials, I want the **ball** to **collide with the edges of the screen**. Of course I can simply put an object and give it a collider and put manually at the edge, but is there a way to make the ball collide with the edge of the camera?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you are trying to do, this will help you obtain an answer.

Comment: You do in fact add colliders to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are 2 things you can try (if you don't want to add 4 colliders around your area) and the first thing you need to understand is that the camera is not actually in the position you are watching in-game view, it is just a projection. The camera is probably way behind so you are not searching for a collision **with the Camera** but a collision with **what the Camera sees**.

1. **ADDING AN EDGE COLLIDER**

The edge collider simply puts a collider around the edges of an object, but it won't work like that because the camera is far behind and so you will need to scale a bit the collider to fit the actual game view.

2. **ADDING A CODE THAT DOES THIS**

This is a bit stupid but can work, I mean, it is way easier to add 4 colliders but I guess you can do it with code and get same result. For example if I want the top border I can use:

```
GameObject top;
void Awake()
 {
     top = new GameObject("Top");
 }


void Start()
{
BoxCollider2D collider = top.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
     collider.size = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)).x - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0f)).x), 0.1f, 0f);
     collider.offset = new Vector2(collider.size.x / 2f, collider.size.y / 2f);

     top.transform.position = new Vector3((Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)).x - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0f)).x) / 2f, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0f)).y, 0f);
}
```

I think this is just a bit dumb to do, because this is just for the top collider, and maybe you should consider a way to work in the inspector with them

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply!! Now I know it isn't something I should do I guess!

Comment: I feel like it is just a bit longer, but you can try the edge collider or add colliders by hand I guess @Nextgengamedeveloper

Comment: Guys you cannot add them by hand ............. in fact you HAVE TO have the code find the correct position at run-time. Because of all the different screen shapes.

Comment: actually you can use the canvas scaling mode and it will still preserve, but I get your point @Fattie

Comment: @Fattie that's why I asked it, so is this the correct way? with those screenToWorldPoint? Thanks

Comment: @Leoverload  Oh I will check it

Comment: @Leoverload - unless I misunderstand you, canvas scaling mode is not relevant at all here. That's UI.

Comment: @Nextgengamedeveloper - basically yes, but there are a number of ways to do it.  Don't forget when the *screen size changes* it has to still work.  It's easy to test that in Editor by just changing the Game screen as you Play.

Comment: Yep! Thanks, will keep that in mind! Now I will post some other questions for this game until I finish it, I will be able to finish the game thanks to this communit! Many thanks